# Simultaneous solving of three equations with nested, complicated expressions

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

I have the following variables s1, s2, and r1 defined as

```
s1 = 12 *g1^2 + 12 *g2^2 - Γ^2 + Γ*κ1 - κ1^2 + (Γ + κ1)*κ2 - κ2^2;
s2 = 4*s1^3 + 9*s1^2*(Γ + κ1 - 2 κ2)^2 + 6*s1*(Γ + κ1 - 2 κ2)*((Γ + κ1 
    -2κ2)^3+ 108*g2^2*(-Γ + κ2)) + ((Γ + κ1 - 2 κ2)^3 + 108*g2^2*(-Γ+κ2))^2;
r1 = Sqrt[s2] - (3*s1 + (Γ + κ1 - 2 κ2)^2)*(Γ + κ1 - 2*κ2) + 108*g2^2*(Γ-κ2);
```

Followed by three equations that contains s1, s2, and r1

```
o1 = 1/6*(Γ + κ1 + κ2 - s1*(2/r1)^(1/3) + (r1/2)^(1/3) - 6*I*ω);
o2 = 1/6*(Γ + κ1 + κ2 + s1*(1 + I*Sqrt[3])/(4*r1)^(1/3) - (1 - I*Sqrt[3])* 
     (r1/16)^(1/3) - 6*I*ω);
o3 = 1/6*(Γ + κ1 + κ2 + s1*(1 - I*Sqrt[3])/(4*r1)^(1/3) - (1 + I*Sqrt[3])* 
     (r1/16)^(1/3) - 6*I*ω);
```

I then wish to solve for the common value of g1 between o1, o2, and o3. I proceed to do

```
Solve[o1==o2==o3,g1]
```

But the compilation time becomes incredibly long (I have yet to compile it successfully). Given how computationally expensive it must be, are there any alternatives to solving the three equations simultaneously for g1 in a faster way?

Thanks!

Comment: NO solution by `NSolve`, Try: `Table[\[CapitalGamma] = 
  RandomReal[{-1000, 1000}, 10][[k]]; \[Kappa]1 = 
  RandomReal[{-1000, 1000}, 10][[k]]; \[Kappa]2 = 
  RandomReal[{-1000, 1000}, 10][[k]]; \[Omega] = 
  RandomReal[{-1000, 1000}, 10][[k]]; 
 g2 = RandomReal[{-1000, 1000}, 10][[k]]; 
 NSolve[o1 == o2 == o3 && -1000 < g1 < 1000, g1], {k, 1, 10}]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thanks for your help but upon running your solution, I was returned with a list with 10 braces: '{{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}'. Moreover, it seems to me that you're replacing the variables with numbers using 'RandomReal' but I need the solution to be in the original algebraic expression. Do you have any ideas on how to go about solving this without substituting numbers?

Comment: @Bill I tried the suggested solution but I was returned with an error saying that parts of the argument in the 'Reduce' function is not a variable. Are there any alternatives to solving this? Thanks

Comment: `NSolve` needs numeric values for variables.From [Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) this 10 brances mean: `No solution 10 times`,because in `Table[expr,{k,1,10}]`.

Comment: @Bill Are you saying that there is no mathematical solution at all for 'o1==o2==o3' in terms of g1 since it returns 'False'?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your first example but from your last comment. my 'AbsoluteTiming' returns '{1.27833, False}' so there's that. But I'm certain that there's a solution to o1, o2 and o3 in terms of g1 from experience. Any suggestions at all on what I should do?

Comment: This `sol=NMinimize[Total[Abs[{Re[o1], Im[o1], Re[o2], Im[o2], Re[o3], Im[o3]}]], {g1, g2, \[CapitalGamma], \[Kappa]1, \[Kappa]2, \[Omega]}, WorkingPrecision->64, MaxIterations->10^4, Method->"RandomSearch"]; {Re[o1]+I Im[o1], Re[o2]+I Im[o2], Re[o3]+I Im[o3]} /. sol[[2]]` finds an approximate numeric solution. Can you show an example from experience which has a symbolic solution? Perhaps that might give some insight.

Comment: @Bill I redefined my variables in a more coherent way this time around and it worked. I think it's just Mathematica throwing a fit if I brute force it for a solution without more simplifications in r1, s1 and s2. Thanks for the help!